# How to fetch the data from Firebase database using multiple where condition in Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want fetch the data from Firebase realtime database using multiple where condition.

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("tblSalesDetails");
Query query = databaseReference.child("authenticationId").child("9591290928").orderByChild("invoiceNo").equalTo(str_invoice_no);
query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        int i=0;
        for(DataSnapshot snap : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Log.d("tag","item ID:");


            TableRow tr = new TableRow(AddItemToSale.this);
            CheckBox Box = new CheckBox(AddItemToSale.this);
            tr.setLayoutParams(getLayoutParams());

            Log.d("tag","item ID:"+snap.child("itemId").getValue(String.class));



            tr.addView(getTextView("0", String.valueOf(i + 1), ContextCompat.getColor(AddItemToSale.this, R.color.colorPrimary), Typeface.NORMAL, R.drawable.high));

            tr.addView(getTextView((snap.child("sdId").getValue(String.class)),snap.child("itemId").getValue(String.class), ContextCompat.getColor(AddItemToSale.this, R.color.colorPrimary), Typeface.NORMAL,R.drawable.high));
            tr.addView(getTextView((snap.child("sdId").getValue(String.class)),snap.child("amount").getValue(String.class), ContextCompat.getColor(AddItemToSale.this, R.color.colorPrimary), Typeface.NORMAL,R.drawable.high));
            tr.addView(getTextView((snap.child("sdId").getValue(String.class)),snap.child("discAmount").getValue(String.class), ContextCompat.getColor(AddItemToSale.this, R.color.colorPrimary), Typeface.NORMAL, R.drawable.high));
            tr.addView(getTextView((snap.child("sdId").getValue(String.class)),snap.child("taxName").getValue(String.class), ContextCompat.getColor(AddItemToSale.this, R.color.colorPrimary), Typeface.NORMAL, R.drawable.high));
            tbl_sales.addView(tr, getTblLayoutParams());

            i++;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The query that you are using is getting you only a single invoice where the `invoiceNo` property is equal to `str_invoice_no`. There is no way you can use multiple "WHERE" clauses in Firebase realtime database. The only solution in which you can filter a property on multiple values in Firebase realtime database is if those invoice numbers are in a range. For instance, you can get all invoices matching some invoice numbers using the following query:

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("tblSalesDetails");
Query query = databaseReference.child("authenticationId").child("9591290928")
    .orderByChild("invoiceNo")
    .startAt("startInvoiceNo")
    .endAt("endInvoiceNo");
```

Please note, there is no way in Firebase realtime database nor in the new [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) database to pass multiple separate values into a query. You will have to execute a separate query for each value and merge them client-side.

Please also check Frank van Puffelen's answer from the following post:

- [firebase equivalent to sql where in ()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29560088/firebase-equivalent-to-sql-where-in)

And for Firestore, please also check my answer from this post:

- [What is the alternate of IN keyword in Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55816070/what-is-the-alternate-of-in-keyword-in-firebase/55816368#55816368)

Comment: i dont want range i want to  fetch the data based on single invoice number with authentication id

Comment: Isn't your actual code doing what you want? Isn't getting a single invoice? As I see, your actual question is: "How to fetch the data from Firebase database using **multiple where condition** in Android". So please be more specific regarding what you are looking to achieve.